# What is the Romulan commander's name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, names

In [TOS: The Enterprise Incident](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/59.htm), the female Romulan commander whispers her name into Spock's ear.

> **COMMANDER:** *Yes. Yes, it will, Mister Spock. You do know I have a first name*.
>
> **SPOCK:** *I was beginning to wonder.*
>
> **COMMANDER:** *Well, I do. Would you like to hear it?*  (She whispers in his ear.)
>
> **SPOCK:** *How rare, and how beautiful. But so incongruous when spoken by a soldier.*

**Does the canon give her name or is it in non-canon only?**

Answer (score 7):

[image]

### Star Trek Apocrypha from Memory Alpha

> - **This [Romulan Commander](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Romulans_%2823rd_century%29#Commander_.282268.29) was played by actress Joanne Linville. The character whispered her name into Spock's ear, and he commented how "rare and beautiful" it was, but it was never spoken aloud.**

### Non-Canon Sources

> - Some non-canon sources, such as authors Josepha Sherman and Susan Shwartz, as well as the Star Trek Customizable Card Game, list the character's name as "Charvanek." Authors Sondra Marshak and Myrna Culbreath list her as "Dion Charvon" in The Price of the Phoenix and The Fate of the Phoenix.
> - Author Della Van Hise lists her as "Praetor Thea" in Killing Time.
> - According to the Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion, Naren Shankar suggested bringing back the Commander in "Face of the Enemy". However Linville was unavailable, and thus the character of Toreth was created instead.

**Ref: [Memory Alpha -> Unnamed Romulan Commander](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Romulans_%2823rd_century%29#Commander_.282268.29)**

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that canon essentially means any of the 5 live action TV shows or any of the movies.  (I know, at least while there were still TV shows and movies in production, that's what producers considered canon.)  (As to if the animated series is canon, well, that's a major debate in itself.)

The Romulan Commander's name is never spoken out loud.  While this is a negative that's hard to prove, all I can say is the local networks used to re-run Trek late at night and would let episodes run over the time slot so the entire episode could play out without anything cut.  At the time video tapes decks were for professionals, but I had a cassette tape recorder I used to record a number of episodes, including *The Enterprise Incident*.  I listened to it many, **many** times (I had no life as a teen in the 1970s and 1980s) and almost memorized it.  Her name was never mentioned in the episode.

As to later discussions, while there may have been brief references to the episode (such as comments about Romulans and cloaking devices), the Commander was never mentioned again.  (I watched for it!)  For a series in the 1960s, that was normal for a TV series.  At that time most shows made each episode a stand-alone with very little references to other episodes.

In the movies or later live action shows, there was never any reference to this event at all, much less to her name.

Comment: recording TOS episodes to audio cassette was not an uncommon practice. When we bought our first house, I found a box of cassettes of at least the first season and probably the second and I wish I had kept them. Sadly, they seemed like trash at the time but now I think it would have nice to have merely for nostalgic purposes.

Answer (score 2):

As I reember, there was a fan parody of the episode in Trek magazine and the Best of Trek books, where the Romulan Commander said her name was "Trampolina".

I also remember that there was an article in Trek which stated that different novels gave five different and  inconistent stories about the Romulan Commander's fate after "The Enterprise Incident".  Reading all of the novels mentioned might lead to another name or two for her.